# Removing initializer on upgrade

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

Is it bad practice to remove the initializer on an upgradable contract on subsequent upgrades? Since the code wont be used any longer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize the newly updated contract.

Once you deploy your new upgradable contract, you will have to initialize it and hook it to your main smart contract, so you will need the initialize function.